# Import and use .uml metamodel in eclipse ATL

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, metamodel, eclipse-atl

I'm currently having trouble using Eclipse ATL.

I create two models in Cameo/MagicDraw and export them in UML2 format to Eclipse. My aim is to use ATL to transform instances of the first model in instances of the second model.

Unfortunatelly, i can't find any elements in my metamodel. I don't know if i don't look properly into them, export them in a bad format or in the bad way.

I try with very simples models :

My two metamodels are with the following structure :

Metamodel 1 : ProjectUsage1.uml
[image: Metamodel 1 : ProjectUsage1.uml]

Metamodel 2 : ProjectUsage2.uml
[image: Metamodel 2 : ProjectUsage2.uml]

Here is my ATL code :
[image: ATL code]
The problem is here in the line 12 where i don't know how to access my class PU1_A from my source metamodel.
I tried several syntax but i don't manage a way to browse my model from  Model >  ProjectUsage1 > PU1_A (all separators i tried don't work (! . :: :)). I dont' know if all my models elements need to be in the root or if there is a trivil way to fix this problem.

Here is the run configuration :
[image: Run configuration]

And here is the error :
[image: Eclipse console error]